# JavaScript - Intercept any ajax request to add parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple JavaScript code to intercept any AJAX request with the idea of add an extra param that I need to read in the server side (Java). Until now I have this code that I have tested with different kind of request, with and without jquery as well, works fine:

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        console.log('Start a new AJAX request');
        var myExtraParam = 'ABC123'; // value that I need to send, but it's dynamically, it will come from a function
        open.apply(this);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

What I have been looking is the way to attach an extra parameter, on this scenario, the variable "myExtraParam" when I call the apply method.

I'm using plain JavaScript

*EDIT*:
As param, I'm asuming a value that I can read in the server, like when you do: `myurl?myExtraParam=ABC123`

Comment: So, you're asking how to add a parameter?  What do you mean?  A query parameter?  Adding it to the payload body?  A header?

Comment: I would set a header...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. `apply()` is for sending an array as parameter.

Comment: You can't add it as a GET parameter when the request is already open, AFAIK. GET parameters are part of the URL and that cannot be changed after `open()` is called. So, you'll probably want to override `open()` instead.

Comment: Also note, in your example `open.apply(this);` will discard the arguments originally passed to `send()`. In such cases you should call `open.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @Amy Any way of parameter that I can read from my servlet.

Comment: @MátéSafranka As this is meant for any kind of request, it also apply for the POST, how can I override the open method, any example?. I have tried with `open.apply(this, arguments);` however I can't get this value in the server

Comment: Okay I just doublechecked your code. You know that `var myExtraParam = 'ABC123'` doesn't actually do anything, right? I mean, it doesn't modify the XHR in any way. So going all the way back to @Amy's question, what exactly do you mean by "adding a parameter"?

Comment: @MátéSafranka Off course, it doesn't do anything, there is exactly my point, I need to send this value, thank you

Comment: @epascarello but how? is only under demand of an AJAX call

Comment: Again: what exactly do you mean by "sending" the value? It can be "sent" in the same request in different ways. It can be added as a URL paramter, or inside the POST payload, or as a HTTP header like @escaparello says. If you're not sure, please research these first, and check the docs on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a parameter seems like a lot of work dealing with querystring or appending it to the request body. Safer thing seems to be using a header.

```
(function() {
  var orgSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
  window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    this.setRequestHeader("foo", "bar")
    return orgSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
  };
})();
```

Comment: Certainly the best option, I have tested this with my servlet and works perfect, thank you